# Divergent sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $(\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_j)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, cesaro-summable

I'm searching for a sequence that diverges as such

### $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

but if inserted in

### $(\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_j)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

it converges.

Comment: See also: [Example of $(b_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac1n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i$ does not exists and $0\le b_n\le 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2370985) and [Convergence of sequence of averages the other way around](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Doesn't $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(-1)^n} = 1$$? So it is convergent as I see it?

Comment: I just watched a proof video why the sequence $$(-1)^n$$ does diverge. Ignore my question above. Thanks.